# Ant input called multiple times if used with ant-contrib foreach task

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have this code snippet inside build.xml file.

```
<input message="Please enter environment:" addproperty="environment" defaultvalue="dev"/>

<target name="DeployComposites">
  <echo>Deploying projects ${composite.list}</echo>
  <foreach list="${composite.list}" param="compositeName" target="compile-and-deploy" inheritall="false"/>
</target>
```

The input prompts multiple times for the property value.Is there a way to make it ask only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `foreach` works it creates a new Ant `Project` for each invocation of the desired target.  Since you have the `input` at the top level it will be called each time a new `Project` is created.

Instead, put it inside another target, for example

```
<target name="get-env">
  <input message="Please enter environment:" addproperty="environment" defaultvalue="dev"/>
</target>

<target name="DeployComposites" depends="get-env">
  <echo>Deploying projects ${composite.list}</echo>
  <foreach list="${composite.list}" param="compositeName" target="compile-and-deploy" inheritall="false"/>
</target>
```

Comment: The problem here is i need to load the property before the ant target . This property inturn loads a property file.

Comment: @Raj so you'd need to move the loading of that property file inside the target as well.

Comment: Moving that would make the properties unavailable for other targets .Is there a way to fix it

Comment: @Raj make the "other targets" depend on this one.

Comment: There are so many targets in my file is there anyother simpe way to do it

Comment: @Raj you could try setting `inheritall="true"` instead of `false` on the `foreach` - an `input` task should be silently skipped if the property it is configured to populate has already been set.